# How many valid parenthesis combinations?

Tags: math, recursion, combinations, discrete-mathematics

We have:

- `n1` number of `{}` brackets ,
- `n2` number of `()` brackets ,
- `n3` number of `[]` brackets ,

How many different valid combination of these brackets we can have?

What I thought: I wrote a brute force code in java (which comes in the following) and counted all possible combinations, I know it's the worst solution possible,

(the code is for general case in which we can have different types of brackets)

Any mathematical approach ?

Note 1: valid combination is defined as usual, e.g. `{{()}}` : valid , `{(}){}` : invalid

Note 2: let's assume that we have 2 pairs of `{}` , 1 pair of `()` and 1 pair of `[]`, the number of valid combinations would be 168 and the number of all possible (valid & invalid) combinations would be 840

```
static void paranthesis_combination(char[] open , char[] close , int[] arr){
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
        l += arr[i];
    l *= 2;
    paranthesis_combination_sub(open , close , arr , new int[arr.length]  , new int[arr.length], new StringBuilder(), l);
    System.out.println(paran_count + " : " + valid_paran_count);
    return;
}


static void paranthesis_combination_sub(char[] open , char[] close, int[] arr , int[] open_so_far , int[] close_so_far, StringBuilder strbld , int l){
    if (strbld.length() == l && valid_paran(open , close , strbld)){
        System.out.println(new String(strbld));
        valid_paran_count++;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < open.length ; i++){
        if (open_so_far[i] < arr[i]){
            strbld.append(open[i]);
            open_so_far[i]++;
            paranthesis_combination_sub(open , close, arr , open_so_far , close_so_far, strbld , l);
            open_so_far[i]--;
            strbld.deleteCharAt(strbld.length() -1 );
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < open.length ; i++){
        if (close_so_far[i] < open_so_far[i]){
            strbld.append(close[i]);
            close_so_far[i]++;
            paranthesis_combination_sub(open , close, arr , open_so_far , close_so_far, strbld , l);
            close_so_far[i]--;
            strbld.deleteCharAt(strbld.length() -1 );
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: How do you define a valid combination?  Depending on the parsing rules, there could be many different answers to this question.

Comment: Question is now edited

Comment: Look up Catalan numbers. Is ({}) valid?

Comment: You know StackExchange got [Math section](http://math.stackexchange.com/)? I  belive they might be better equipped with math answers :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C`<sub>`n`</sub> is the nth Catalan number, `C(2n,n)/(n+1)`, and gives the number of valid strings of length `2n` that use only `()`.  So if we change all `[]` and `{}` into `()`, there would be `C`<sub>`n1+n2+n3`</sub> ways.  Then there are `C(n1+n2+n3,n1)` ways to change `n1` `()` back to `{}`, and `C(n2+n3,n3)` ways to change the remaining `()` into `[]`.  Putting that all together, there are `C(2n1+2n2+2n3,n1+n2+n3)C(n1+n2+n3,n1)C(n2+n3,n3)/(n1+n2+n3+1)` ways.

As a check, when `n1=2`, `n2=n3=1`, we have `C(8,4)C(4,2)C(2,1)/5=168`.

Comment: Good job! The Catalan numbers were mentioned in the beginning but I was too lazy to check it up :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, infinitely. However I assume, that you meant to find how many combinations are there provided limited string length. For simplicity lets assume that the limit is an even number. Then, lets create an initial string:

(((...()...))) with length equal to the limit.

Then, we can switch any instance of () pair with [] or {} parenthesis. However, if we change an opening brace, then we ought to change the matching closing brace. So, we can look only at the opening braces, or at pairs. For each parenthesis pair we have 4 options:

- leave it unchanged
- change it to []
- change it to {}
- remove it

So, for each of (l/2) objects we choose one of four labels, which gives:
**4^(l/2)** possibilities.

EDIT: this assumes only "concentric" parenthesis strings (contained in each other), as you've suggested in your edit. Intuitively however, a valid combination is also: ()[]{} - this solution does not take this into account.

Comment: As I said, we have specific number for each pair ( `n1` of `{}` brackets) so it cannot be infinite and I am assuming `()[]{}` to be valid !

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the numbers. I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: I added a sample input and output

Comment: I give up, for now :P

Comment: Changing everything to `()` ends up being a good way to start.  Thanks for the idea.